# How to set an NSNumber from one class to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm attempting to add a class into my view, and also set a NSNumber while I do so. However the number keeps getting returned as null, and I'm just a little confused as to why. Could someone help me?

```
 SelectionOptions* newClass = [[SelectionOptions alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140.0f, 80.0f, 620.0f, 610.0f)];


[self.superview addSubview:newClass];
 [[self.superview.subviews lastObject] setMyNSNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];
```

**From New Class

NSLog(@"Check the number : %@", myNSNumber);

Comment: Can we see how you're creating the `newClass` object (at least I hope it's an object instance)? Also, the code you're using to determine that it "keeps getting returned as null"...

Comment: Why not `[newClass setMyNSNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];`?

Comment: tried that, didnt seem to work...

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the SelectionOptions.h file and the accessor method(s) (or property details) for `myNSNumber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a number in secondview and do this

secondclass.number = presentnumber;